# new In app purchases product for current app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on in app purchases for content downloading.

Product list will return from the server and product id also. I am not clear about one thing:

Can I add new in app purchases without updating the app ? Because the product list will come from server side.

I just want to add In App Purchases from iTunesConnect and the product list on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can  add new in app purchases without update the app.

You will need to add all of your product to iTunes connect & for sure get Apple approval.

When you return product like reten it with same IAP ID.

Comment: How did you add it without it showing up to your current users. and only show up for testing and to get approval from apple?

Comment: I would like to know this, too. This solved my issue (answer of Charlie Seligman): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058997/new-in-app-purchases-products-added-to-second-version-not-being-returned-by-appl