# New In App Purchases products added to second version not being returned by apple

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase

I currently have an app in the Apple App Store with x2 In App Purchase products.

I am now trying to created a second version (v1.1) and have added 2 additional in app purchase products.  However, when I go to apple the old product ids are returned in the delegate method below, but the new product ids are not being returned?

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

I have checked they are fully added in the in app purchase section of itunes connect and they are all 'awaiting screenshot', which I cant get to since they are not being returned by Apple.

Has anyone else come across this issue? And a resolution?

Comment: Upload any screenshot over over there & Then try..

Comment: Tried uploading a screenshot from another app but that didnt resolve it unfortunately.

Comment: How long ago did you register the items?

Comment: I think new items is not added into inapp purchase section. Make sure that all the items are approved.

Comment: did you change your app version in plist to newest one(v1.1)? probably they will be active after that version. And another thing is if you are running in release mode you should change it to debug mode.

Comment: - Registered the items over a week ago.
- Items are all 'Ready to Submit' - since cant submit them until I have valid screenshots
- app version in plist already set at v1.1

Think I might need to use my service call to Apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh!  I wasnt passing in my new in app purchase product ids into the following, so Apple wasnt looking for them to return the details:
[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];

Hopefully this answer might help someone else in the future.  Just used up one of my annual Apple tickets to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the bundle version is 1.1
2. Wait several hours. it might take some time before the new product is synchronized to the sandbox server. Apple is complained a lot by developers about the delay.